# Prove: $x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}y+x^{2n-2}y^2+\cdots +y^{2n}\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, proof-verification

### Exercise:

> Prove that $$x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}y+x^{2n-2}y^2+\cdots +y^{2n}\geq 0$$

---

### Attempt:

I'm not sure where to begin with this problem, so I don't really have anything to show.

---

### Request:

There's no need to give me the whole solution (though it is welcome so that those who need it will have it); I just need a hint to kickstart my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the expression is symmetric in $x,y$ so we can assume WLOG that $x \ge y$. If $x=y$ then the expression reduces to $(2n+1)x^{2n} \ge 0$ otherwise multiplying by $x-y \gt 0$ gives $x^{2n+1}-y^{2n+1} \gt 0$ which holds true  because $x \gt y$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the factorisation of $x^{2n+1}-y^{2n+1}$. What if $x \le y$? What if $x>y$?

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$ then $f(x,y)=y^{2n}\ge 0$, else pose $c=y/x$

$f(x,y)=x^{2n}(1+c+c^2+...+c^{2n})=x^{2n}(\frac{1-c^{2n+1}}{1-c})$ numerator and denominator of the fraction are the same sign, the whole thing multiplied by a square, so it is positive.

Comment: yep, corrected, thx.